# Rule - Search for my name in outlook messages but ignoring the text inserted in replies

Tags: outlook, query

I get a lot of junk emails that require no action from me so I wanted to filter out those that have my name in the body/subject and put them into a special folder.

I realized after creating the rule that replying to an email chain inserts plaintext with a list of recipients, often including myself. So the rule isn't very useful. eg

```
Reply body here
_____
From: ...
...
To: **Lastname, Me** <me@company.com>
```

So it picks up the "To" portion in the body search

I can't figure out a way to do this so I'm thinking it may not be possible, unless there's a way to do a nested AND like

```
Body or subject includes "Myname"
but not (body or subject !includes "Myname" and includes "**Lastname, Me** <me@company.com>"
```

Any thoughts on how I might achieve that?

Comment: The requirement to prioritize mail that not only is addressed at you, but also mentions your name another time sounds like a symptom of something else going really wrong. What makes you think you should be focusing on specially treating certain mail directed at you - instead of making sure mail not meant for you does not land in your personal inbox in the first place?

Comment: This is at a fortune 500 company where paralysis by analysis is embedded in the culture and reply all is used when it shouldn't be. I don't really think "change the company culture" is a valid response to the question

Answer (score 1):

I think the search folder could help.
New Search Folder -> Create a custom... -> Criteria -> Advanced -> Filed=Subject Condition=doesn't contain Value=RE: -> Add to list.
Then modify other properties, that works for me.
Seems I couldn't post pictures:(